# Trouble using python dictionary in a Django template

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, dictionary

So I have a python dictionary storing the size and the amount each size has, titled `final_list`. Then I'm passing that to the template using `"sizes": final_list`. In the html template, I'm trying to create a drop-down selection with all the sizes, and only display sizes that are available, or have an amount not equal to 0. The problem is, it seems as if it isn't accepting the dict or something, since the dropdown shows up empty. Below is the code I have, any help would be much appreciated.

**Views.py**

I'm getting the sizing info from a model called 'Size' then checking if there are 0 objects of that size. Then I'm creating the dictionary to only have sizes that are actually available.

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)

def product(request, code):
    sizes = Size.objects.get(code=code)
    all_size = ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'XL']
    final_list = {}
    for size in all_size:
        if getattr(sizes, size) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            final_list[size] = getattr(sizes, size)
    return render(request, "website/listing.html", {
        "sizes": final_list
    })
```

**HTML (website/listing.html)**

```
<form method="POST">
  <select name="sizes" style="width: 90px; height: 20px;">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {% for size in sizes %}
     {% if final_list|get_item:size != 0 %}
        <option>{{size}}</option>
     {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Why did you use a *custom filter*?  You can use ***dot operator*** to get the value from a dict as, ***`final_list.size`***

Comment: @ArakkalAbu No you can't. `size` is a variable, not the string literal `"size"`. The key itself is either `small`, `medium`, `large`, or `XL`.

Comment: @Selcuk Oh... I see. I didn't notice that, btw, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass a context variable named `final_list` to the template. You should use `{% if sizes|get_item ...` instead.

That being said, this code could be simplified as:

```
{% for size, value in sizes.items %}
    {% if value %}
        <option>{{ size }}</option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This way you don't have to use the custom filter `get_item` either.

Comment: Okay, so that seems to solve the problem of the dictionary showing up, but instead of showing up as drop-down options, they show up under the drop down as plain text. Do you know a way to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean? Obviously this code needs to be between `<select>` and `</select>` tags. Also you should take `{% csrf_token %}` out of the `select` block.

Comment: The code was between the select tags, but the CSRF token in the wrong place was causing the problems, it works now, thanks!